# How to replace new paragraph characters with newline characters in LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: libreoffice-writer

I'm copying a lot of source code into LibreOffice Writer. It is inserted with new paragraph line ending instead of newline line ending. That consumes a lot of vertical space and make document look ugly.

I'm looking for quickest way to make lines ended with newline characters.

Answer (score 1):

Is it not the Default style that you are using that has spacing before each paragraph.  I generally set-up a Code style (with no additional line spacing) and apply that to all my code examples.

Put your cursor into some of the code, and then press <kbd>F11</kbd> to display the Styles and Formatting box.  This will highlight the style that you are using, right click the style and select Modify to adjust the line spacing.

Answer (score 0):

When I try to do this kind of thing I turn to the [Alternative dialog Find & Replace](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/alternative-dialog-find-replace-for-writer) extension. I don't know if it is compatible with LibreOffice 3.6x, but it works with previous versions. With regular expressions activated I replace `\p` with `\n` in whatever area of the document that I have selected.